# Singular value decomposition for unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, unitary-matrices

I know the title is strange, but there are many instances in [quantum information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_information) in which one is interested not in diagonalizing a unitary matrix, but instead in finding its singular value decomposition (SVD) — the theorem of existence is Cor. 2.4 in [Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information). I was checking how to actually compute this decomposition in [here](https://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm), but the example is based in the usual rectangular matrix $A$ with real entries.

In order to compute $A = USV$, one needs to compute $W = AA^T$ (where $\cdot^T$ denotes the transpose) and the eigenvectors of $W$ form the columns of $U$. Likewise, the eigenvectors of $\tilde{W} = A^T A$  form the columns of $V$. Finally, $S$ is a diagonal matrix in which the nonzero entries are the squared root of the eigenvalues of $W$.

How would this be modified if $A$ is unitary? Obviously, $A A^\dagger = \mathbb{1}$, so it seems still needed that $W = AA^T$ (is this correct?). What about the diagonal values of $S$? Shouldn't carry a complex conjugation aside from the square root?

Comment: $A$ is unitary and rectangular? Does it mean that the rows (or columns) are orthogonal and unit normed?

Comment: $A$ is a squared unitary matrix. In this case yes, the columns form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: In the general (not necessarily real) case you rather have $W=AA^{\dagger}$ and $\bar{W}=A^{\dagger}A$, as well as $A=USV^{\dagger}$.

Answer (score 5):

In the complex setting, a singular value decomposition is given by a factorization $A = US V^\dagger$ where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices of the appropriate sizes and $S$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries. (Here, $(\cdot)^\dagger$ is the adjoint/conjugate transpose.) If $A$ is unitary, then one singular value decomposition is attained by setting $U = A$ and $S = V = I$ (for $I$ the identity matrix). Another is given by $U = S = I$ and $V = A^\dagger$. Indeed, for *any* unitary matrix $U$, setting $S = I$ and $V = A^\dagger U$ gives a singular value decomposition of $A$.

The key observation is that all of $A$'s singular values are equal to $1$ (this follows by the fact that $A^\dagger A = AA^\dagger =I$ which has all ones for eigenvalues). The singular vectors are not unique: the singular subspaces associated with a single singular value are unique. As such, for unitary $A$, there is one singular subspace consisting of all vectors, and a singular value decomposition can be constructed by any unitary matrix $U$ whose columns will form a basis for this space.

Comment: But is it still possible to find an SVD using the trick $AA^T$ and $A^T A$ (if one considers that $A$ contains only real entries)?